# What is the difference between index.html and index.html.erb in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to look up the index.html file in the 'public' directory but it doesn't appear there.

I only find index.html.erb in 'Posts' directory.

My route.rb says the following:

> resources :posts
>   root 'posts#index'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index.html` is a static file. If you want static html files, you don't need Ruby on Rails. You want it to be dynamic. You want it to show your posts from your database.

`index.html.erb` is dynamic, the content is handled by rails before sending it to the browser.

If you have a webserver with static pages, and you just request the domain name, the webserver is normally give you back the static file `index.html`.

But remember, we don't want static pages. So the `root` command in the `route.rb` file specifies what to do when you request only the domain name. It specifies that the `index`-action of the `PostsController` is called. This action then will then render your `index.html.erb` template in the Posts directory.

Comment: Thank you. It is now clearer in my mind and this will help me to further dig into Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

`erb` stands for "Embedded RuBy". `.erb.html` file is a file where you can put html and ruby codes together.

For example:

```
<%= link_to "Dashboard",root_path%> #ruby code 

<a>Dashboard</a>
```

In `.html` file you can put only html codes.